# How do I select boolean value in DataTable c#?

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a database table with two columns such as Name -varchar(50) and Valid -boolen

```
----------------
Name    Valid
----------------
John    True
John    False
----------------
```

I have to select only if Name is 'John' and Valid is 'True'. I tried the below code but it doesn't return any thing. Please help me in this regard.

```
conList = conTable.Select(string.Format(@"Name='{0}' AND Valid='True'", "John")).ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use LINQ(-To-DataTable):

```
var rows = from row in conTable.AsEnumerable()
           where row.Field<bool>("Valid") && row.Field<string>("Name") == "John"
           select row;
```

If you want a new `DataTable` from the result use:

```
DataTable filtered = rows.CopyToDataTable();
```

or you can loop the rows in a `foreach` or create a different collection with `ToArray` or `ToList`.

All in one via method syntax (not more efficient):

```
DataTable filtered = conTable.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(row => row.Field<bool>("Valid") && row.Field<string>("Name") == "John")
    .CopyToDataTable();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use linq for that. example is below.

```
List<DataRow> dataRows = (from DataRow dr in yourTable.Rows 
                          where (bool)dr["Valid"] == true && (string)dr["Name"] == "John" 
                          select dr).ToList();

dataRows.ForEach(p => Console.WriteLine("Name : {0}, Valid : {1}", p["Name"], p["Valid"]));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
conList = conTable.Select(string.Format(@"Name='{0}' AND Valid", "John")).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If Linq is not an option, you can filter boolean columns in a DataTable in the same way you would filter a table containing a bit column in sql.

Below is a sample I quickly put together to filter a datatable containing a data column of type bool

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("Bit", typeof(bool));

dt.Rows.Add(1, true);
dt.Rows.Add(2, true);
dt.Rows.Add(3, false);
dt.Rows.Add(4, true);

// Fetch all columns that have bit set to true
var dr = dt.Select("Bit=1");
Console.WriteLine("ID\tBit");
foreach(DataRow r in dr)
{
 Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", r["ID"], r["Bit"]);
}
Console.WriteLine();

// Fetch all columns that have bit set to false
dr=dt.Select("Bit=0");
Console.WriteLine("ID\tBit");
foreach (DataRow r in dr)
{
Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", r["ID"], r["Bit"]);
}
Console.WriteLine();
Console.ReadLine();
```

I know the question is old but it was the first search result before figuring it out on my own.